# Trouble with fct_reorder in function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create a function that generates boxplots for different columns of data. I wanted to reorder the factors in ascending order of the y-variable. It works when I don't use a function, i.e.,

```
data(mpg)

ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fct_reorder(class, hwy), y = hwy))
```

Which results in this:

[image]

But if I try to create a function to examine different variables using the `map()` function, I get an error:

```
bp <- function(param){
parameter <- mpg[,param]
ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fct_reorder(class, parameter)))
}

target_parameters <- c("hwy", "cty")

grid.arrange(grobs = map(target_parameters, bp))

Error in fct_reorder(as.factor(class), parameter) : 
  length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has a couple of issues. Firstly, you are using an argument called `parameter`, where it should be `param`. Secondly, you haven't mapped a variable to the y axis (only the x axis). Thirdly, the string is not being converted into a column name inside `fct_reorder`

If you want to pass the variable as a string rather than a bare symbol, you can use `.data[[param]]`

```r
bp <- function(param){
  ggplot(data = mpg) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fct_reorder(class, .data[[param]]), .data[[param]]))
}

bp("hwy")
```

[image]

This also works within your `map` example:

```r
target_parameters <- c("hwy", "cty")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = map(target_parameters, bp))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! There is one thing I forgot to mention. I am trying to use this with the grid.arrange(grobs = map()) function. For example, target_parameters <- c("hwy", "cty"), then grid.arrange(grobs = map(target_parameters, bp)). This generates the error even with the curly-curly operator.

Comment: @KansasKeeton that's because you `target_parameters` are strings. It works just fine using the `.data` version. See my update.

Comment: Ahhhhh, you're amazing! That totally worked. Thank you so much for all your help!